# Trying to add levels to my swift sprite kit game

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I'm trying to add one simple level to my flappy bird styled game. I figure a way of doing it using 2 different scenes but would prefer it to be within the same one. I simply want the walls to appear more frequently once a score of 15 has been reached! Here is my code

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {


    if gameStarted == false{

        gameStarted = true

        body.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = true



        let spawn = SKAction.run({
            () in

            self.createWalls()

        })
        let delay = SKAction.wait(forDuration: 2.0)
        let spawnDelay = SKAction.sequence([delay, spawn])
        let spawnDelayForever = SKAction.repeatForever(spawnDelay)
        self.run(spawnDelayForever)


        let distance = CGFloat(self.frame.width + wallPair.frame.width)
        let movePipes = SKAction.moveBy(x: -distance - 50, y: 0, duration: TimeInterval( 0.01 * distance))
        let removePipes = SKAction.removeFromParent()
        moveAndRemove = SKAction.sequence([movePipes,removePipes])




        body.physicsBody?.velocity = CGVector(dx: 0, dy: 0)
        body.physicsBody?.applyImpulse(CGVector(dx: 0, dy: 68))
       run(flap)


        }
```

Ive tried adding a if statement before which was an if statement like

if score = 20{

but that just delays applying impulse till the player has a score of 20.

Is there a way I can say

```
if score is between 0 and 20 then run my first spawning action
```

then another saying if score > 20 run my second spawning action which would just have a slower spawning time?

Hope this makes sense! Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could move the `spawnDelayForever` logic into a function and call it first with the 2 second delay as parameter, then when the game score gets to 20, call the `spawnDelayForever` function again passing 5 as input parameter. You would need to add the action using a key.

```
self.run(spawnDelayForever(withDelay: 2.0), withKey: "spawnDelayForever")
```

Then remove the running action before adding again.

```
self.removeAction(forKey: "spawnDelayForever")
self.run(spawnDelayForever(withDelay: 5.0), withKey: "spawnDelayForever")
```

Your code might look something like this.

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    if gameStarted == false {
        gameStarted = true
        body.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = true

        self.run(spawnDelayForever(withDelay: 2.0), withKey: "spawnDelayForever")
        // other code...

    } else if score > 20 && spawnDelayApplied == false {
        self.removeAction(forKey: "spawnDelayForever")
        self.run(spawnDelayForever(withDelay: 5.0), withKey: "spawnDelayForever")
        spawnDelayApplied = true
    }
}

func spawnDelayForever(withDelay sec: TimeInterval) -> SKAction {
    let spawn = SKAction.run({
        () in
        self.createWalls()
    })

    let delay = SKAction.wait(forDuration: sec)
    let spawnDelay = SKAction.sequence([delay, spawn])

    return SKAction.repeatForever(spawnDelay)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that I'll give it a go and let you know! Would I need to set up a Bool statement for spawnDelayApplied?

Comment: Yes, create a class level variable for `spawnDelayApplied`, just so you only apply the delay once.